# CSS background image error 'couldn't resolve file'

Tags: html, css

When I launch the page directly from IntelliJ, the images do load. When I launch it from the file, the images don't load.

If I put the two dots at the start of the path, I get the error "couldn't resolve file". When I do this, the images won't load even if I launch from IntelliJ.

This is the CSS:

```
background: url("/images/productos/lat1.jpg") no-repeat
            center center/cover;
```

Things I have tried:

```
background: URL("../images/productos/lat1.jpg") no-repeat
            center center/cover;
```

```
background: url(/images/productos/lat1.jpg) no-repeat
            center center/cover;
```

```
background: URL(../images/productos/lat1.jpg) no-repeat
            center center/cover;
```

I cannot change the location of the images because this is for a school project and the teacher requires a specific folder structure.

EDIT: this worked:

```
background: URL("../../images/productos/lat1.jpg") no-repeat
            center center/cover;
```

Comment: What is the folder structure? Where is the CSS file and where are the images?

Comment: You probably need just one dot, if the CSS file is in the root directory or you put the CSS inside a style tag.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax below is definitely correct:

```
background: url(../images/productos/lat1.jpg);
```

You did not use this type above.
If it still doesn't work then you should check the path you wrote.

The folder "images" must be next to your main file, for example, index.html

so check your path again